# Regex - match URL, but not deeper levels

Tags: regex, url

I'm updating site where I have little control over the content structure or engine, so I must conditionally render a widget depending on URL match.

I need my code to execute when Regex match

```
www.example.com/index.php/category
```

but **NOT** when it matches

```
www.example.com/index.php/category/subcategory
```

I've made this far by far: `www\.example\.[^.]+/category`, but unfortunatly this also matches both aformentioned cases, while I need it to match only a second one. Can you please suggest, how to stop Regex at first */category*, instead of matching further URLs?

Comment: Anchor the regex with either `$` or lookahead, depending on where and how you're matching the url.

Comment: Your regex won't match any of the cases!

Comment: @CinCout  Yes, sorry, I realized that I wrote this sample before it turned out that link contains "index.php" in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this expression might likely work:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[^.]+\.[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?:\/)?$
```

We can also explicitly define the `example.com`:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?example\.com\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?:\/)?$
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rBjPmj/1/)

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/b7rUOy/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/b7rUOy/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your regex won't match any of the cases since you are looking for characters except `.` in between `www.example.` and `/category` but clearly `index.php` has a `.` in it.

Use the following instead:

`www\.example\.\S+\/category$`

Here I am anchoring the end of the search string via `$`, and looking for at least one non-whitespace character in between `www.example.` and `/category`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XzVHKc/2)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realized that I wrote this sample before it turned out that link contains "index.php" in the middle. Your answer was correct, and I implemented this, and works perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follow pattern to match your Url string upto category

```
^www.example.com\/\S+\/category$
```

You can check [here](https://regex101.com/r/DJkAfY/3) for further explanation and experiment on how it works.